# Plotting exponential graphs in matplotlib - ytick spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I'm fairly new to matplotlib and graphing in general, so I'm sorry if this problem sounds trivial.

I'm trying to plot a line graph with following x and y values.

`x_values = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]`

`y_values = [6, 14, 39, 124, 553, 1718, 5524]`

The problem is, since the `y_values` are exponential, you can't really see the lower values on the graph. I've tried to play around with yticks, but the proportions stay the same. **Is there any way to plot this, so you can see all the values?** I would love to have something like fixed spacing between yticks or something similar.

My current code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
y_values = [6, 14, 39, 124, 553, 1718, 5524]

plt.plot(np.array(x_values), np.array(y_values))
plt.xticks(np.arange(18, 25, 1), ('18', '+19', '+20', '+21', '+22', '+23', '+24'))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

[image: plot]

```
plt.yticks(np.concatenate((np.arange(0, 175, 25), [553], [1718], [5524]), axis=None))
```

This would be my goal, but with better y-axis proportions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're just looking for a log scale?

```
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.yticks(y_values, y_values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I actually tried log scale before, but didn't change the yticks to match my values, so the axis looked really weird.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be happy with this? it shows the original plot and next to it a view of the lower values?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
y_values = [6, 14, 39, 124, 553, 1718, 5524]

plt1 = plt.subplot(121)
plt1.margins(0.05)
plt1.plot(np.array(x_values), np.array(y_values), 'k')
plt1.set_title("Original Graph")
plt1.grid()

plt2 = plt.subplot(122)
plt2.margins()
plt2.plot(np.array(x_values[:4]), np.array(y_values[:4]), 'r')
plt2.set_title("Zoom of Lower Values")
plt2.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: This is what the plots look like]